# Unexpected errors found in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am getting errors such as

> Unexpected token LBRACE found
>   it points to `</div>`

I am also getting errors like:

> Unexpected character(s) ';',' ' found
>   That points to lines without any such characters like smarty code:

```
{if isset($payopts[l].shipping) && $payopts[l].shipping}
```

So whats up with that and more importantly, wtf is netbeans talking about?

Comment: I have the same situation. Have you found a solution or at least the cause of the problem?

Comment: I disabled a ton of validations and never looked back.